# Heatmap color range based on max & min value

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to leverage this example for my visualization
https://bl.ocks.org/Bl3f/cdb5ad854b376765fa99

It pretty much works except this part

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.threshold()
        .domain([0.85, 1])
        .range(["#2980B9", "#E67E22", "#27AE60", "#27AE60"]);
```

I basically want a standard vibgyor visualization based on min & max value of the values in csv data?

Any suggestions, how I can modify the above example.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a Violet–Indigo–Blue–Green–Yellow–Orange–Red scale, you can use [`d3.interpolateRainbow`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic/blob/master/README.md#interpolateRainbow) with a sequential scale.

Then, set your domain using the min and max in your values, like any other continuous scale.

Here is a basic example. Suppose this data:

```
const data = [12, 43, 76, 54, 87, 91, 17, 42, 36];
```

We set the scale like this:

```
const scale = d3.scaleSequential()
    .domain(d3.extent(data))
    .interpolator(d3.interpolateRainbow);
```

Running demo:

```js
const data = [12, 43, 76, 54, 87, 91, 17, 42, 36];

const scale = d3.scaleSequential()
  .domain(d3.extent(data))
  .interpolator(d3.interpolateRainbow);

d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d => scale(d))
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Have in mind that this scale won't work for the specific example you linked, since that uses the old D3 v3.